# Which method of password storage is more secure

Tags: encryption, hash, passwords

Which is the more secure method of storing passwords?  I lack the mathematical background to determine the answer myself.

Let's please for the sake of argument assume that all passwords and usernames generated for each of the following methods are randomly generated 6 characters known to be exactly six alpha-humeric-special-character fields and that each are using the same hashing algorithm and the same number of passes.

1. The standard way. UserName stored in plain text and only the password is to be discovered. Hash(PlaintextPassword + UniqueRecordSalt) = Password stored in DB.
2. One field recognized as LoginInfo = Hash(Encryption(UserName, Password) + Shared Salt). Neither the UserName nor the Password are ever stored in any other format EVER.

Does the forced cross attempting of username/password combinations offset the weakness of a shared salt as opposed to a unique record salt? This is of course completely IGNORING all affects on usability and focusing entirely on security.

Can anyone point me to any software to help me answer this question myself since I lack the cryptography and mathematical knowledge to arrive at the answer myself?

Please feel free to move this to a more appropriate forum.  I didn't know where else to put it.  However, I don't feel that it is a topic irrelevant to programmers overall doing their everyday job.

Comment: are you looking for one way hash or two way means encrypt using a key and decrypt using that key ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about security related to storing passwords; not a specific programming problem.

Comment: @user1096646: As commented in the answers below, have a look on security.stackexchange or crypto.stackexchange, where you'll find this question has been addressed before.

Answer (score 1):

As you say option 1 is the standard way to store passwords. As long as you use a secure hash function (eg. [NIST recommend PBKDF2](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-132/nist-sp800-132.pdf)) with a unique salt, your passwords are secure. So I would recommend this option.

Option 2 doesn't really make sense. You cant 'undo' a hash function, so why encrypt its contents? You would then also have to store the encryption key somewhere which is different issue entirely.

Also what do you mean by a shared salt? If you always use the same salt then that defeats the point of salting your hashes. A unique salt per row is the way to go.

I would say that combining the username and password into a single hash is overcomplicating things, and limits your options in development, since you can't get a row from the DB given a username.

Say you want to lock out a user after 5 incorrect password attempts. With a standard plain-text username and hashed pw, you can just have a 'login_attempt_count' column and update the row for that user each time their password is incorrectly entered.

If your username and passwords are hashed together, you have no way of identifying which row to update with a login attempt count, since a hashed correct username with a wrong password wont match any hash.
I guess you could have some kind of mapping function to get a row_id given a username, but I would say its just needlessly complicated, and with greater complication you have a bigger chance of security flaws.

As I said, I would just go with option 1. It's the industry standard way to store passwords, and its secure enough for pretty much any application (as long as you use a modern secure hash function).

Comment: PBKDF2 is a standard password hashing technique.  SHA-1 is not (except when SHA-1 is the native hash used by PBKDF2).

Comment: Yea you're right, i've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [How to securely hash passwords?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/39623) first.  To summarize:

- Never use a single pass of any hashing algorithm.
- Never roll your own, which is what your example 2 is (and example 1 as well, if + means concatenation).
- Username stored in the clear
- Salt generated per user, 8-16 random bytes, stored in the clear

  - in pure binary or encoded into Base64 or hex or whatever you like.
- Use BCrypt, SCrypt, or PBKDF2

  - Until some time after the results of the [Password Hashing Competition](https://password-hashing.net/), at least.
- Use as high an work factor/cost/iteration count as your CPU's can handle during expected future peak times.
- For PBKDF2 in particular, do not ask for more binary output bytes than the native hash produces.  I would say not less than 20 binary bytes, regardless.

  - SHA-1: output = 20 bytes (40 hex digits)
  - SHA-224: 20 bytes <= output <= 28 bytes (56 hex digits)
  - SHA-256: 20 bytes <= output <= 32 bytes (64 hex digits)
  - SHA-384: 20 bytes <= output <= 48 bytes (96 hex digits)
  - SHA-512: 20 bytes <= output <= 64 bytes (128 hex digits)
- For PBKDF2 in particular, SHA-384 and SHA-512 have a comparative advantage on 64-bit systems for the moment, as 2014 vintage GPU's many attackers will use have a smaller margin of advantage for 64-bit operations over your defensive CPU's than they would on 32-bit operations.

If you want an example, then perhaps look at [PHP source code](http://php.net/git.php), in particular the password_hash() and password_verify() functions, per the [PHP.net Password Hashing FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php).

Alternately, I have a variety of (currently very crude) password hashing examples at [my github repositories](https://github.com/Anti-weakpasswords).  Right now it's almost entirely PBKDF2, but I will be adding BCrypt, SCrypt, and so on in the future.